# Display file icons from generated file list in swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to do one thing in Swing, I hope I will be clear enough.

I want to display a list of files with the icons, that the user have associated with that particular file, based on extension. However, I want this list of files be generated in the program - by that I mean: the displayed file icons will *not* be actual files in a folder (so I can't use `JFileChooser`).

Is there anything that can help me with this?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder how you can find the icon associated with files on a given operating system.  Good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This works well. I have taken ideas from [this](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-display-a-jlist-with-icons-and-text) and [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/89) article.

The idea is, I create a classic `JList`, but I add a custom `ListCellRenderer` to paint the icons, which are taken from temporary files trough `JFileChooser`. The resulting renderer looks like this (I made the fields static, so they are not recreated each time the `JList` is made):

```
package app;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
public class PseudofileIconRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static HashMap<String, Icon> extIcons = new HashMap<String, Icon>();
    private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.\\w+$");
    private static JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {


    JLabel label =
            (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
            value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);


    String filename = (String) value;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);
    Icon i;
    String extension = m.find() ? m.group() : "";
    if (extIcons.containsKey(extension)) {
        i = extIcons.get(extension);
    } else  {
        File file;
        try {
            file = File.createTempFile("icon", extension);
            file.deleteOnExit();

            i = chooser.getIcon(file);
            extIcons.put(extension, i);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //this shouldn't happen anyway
            i = null;
        }
    }

    label.setIcon(i);

    return label;
}
```

I can, then, fill the `JList` with `String`s, that will represent the files.

Answer (score 5):

Hi I came across this while googling... hop![alt text][1]e this helps:)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class IconExtract1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String s = "c:/windows/regedit.exe";
File file = new File(s);

// Get metadata and create an icon
sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder sf =
        sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder(file);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));
System.out.println("type = " + sf.getFolderType());

// show the icon
JLabel ficon = new JLabel(s, icon, SwingConstants.LEFT);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(ficon);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

another way:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class IconExtract2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String s = "c:/windows/regedit.exe";
File file = new File(s);

// Get metadata and create an icon
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);

// show the icon
JLabel ficon = new JLabel(s, icon, SwingConstants.LEFT);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(ficon);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

here is the link: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it wrong. This, for some reason, doesn't work in OS X - it returns the same icon for each file. The solution in my own answer works there.

Answer (score 1):

One ugly hack I just now thought of, I don't know if it will work.

I can create a temporary folder, then put empty files with the same filenames in there and then present a `JFileChooser` on that folder, then, after the window closes, delete that folder.

I would prefer a "cleaner" solution, though.